# PHP file stream data coming back in Binary

Tags: php, file, networking, stream

So I have a function that I CANNOT get to work. What's happening is it's coming back with data that's in binary and not the actual file. However, in the binary that I get back, the name of the particular file is included in the string. The data looks like this:

```
PK‹Mpt-BR/finalinport.html³)°S(ÉÈ,V¢‘ŒT…‚ü¢’ÒôÒÔâT…´Ì¼Ä ™” “I,QðT(ÏÌÉQ(-ÈÉOLQH„¨‡*Ê/B×]’X”žZ¢`£_`ÇPK.Ùô LePK‹M.Ùô Lept-BR/finalinport.htmlPKD
```

pt-BR is the directory and the 'finalinport.html' is the file that I am trying to have downloaded. If I replace the second parameter of fwrite to just a plain string, then everything works and I get the string that I wrote in a file inside of the zip. But not when I'm using Stream->getContents(), which leads me to believe that it is something going on with the stream. I cannot wrap my head around what can be happening. I've been on this for a week and a half now so any suggestions would be great.

```
public function downloadTranslations(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $target_locales = $request->input("target_locale");
        $has_source = $request->input("source");
        $client = new API(Auth::user()->access_token, ZKEnvHelper::env('API_URL', 'https://myaccount.com'));
        $document = Document::find($id);
        $job_document = JobDocument::where('document_id', $id)->first();
        $job = Job::find($job_document->job_id);

        $file = tempnam('tmp', 'zip');
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        $zip->open($file, ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);
        $name_and_extension = explode('.', $document->name);

        if($target_locales == null){
            $target_locales = [];
            foreach ($job->target_languages as $target_language) {
                $target_locales[] = $target_language['locale'];
            }
        }

        foreach($target_locales as $target_locale){
            $translation = $client->downloadDocument($document->document_id, $target_locale);
            $filename = $name_and_extension[0] . ' (' . $target_locale . ').' . $name_and_extension[1];
            if($translation->get('message') == 'true') {
                //API brings back file in stream type
                $stream = Stream::factory($translation->get('body'));
                $newFile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'lingo');

                $handle = fopen($newFile, 'w');
                fwrite($handle, $stream->getContents());
                    $zip->addFile($newFile, 'eh.html');
                fclose($handle);
                }

                else if($translation->get('message') == 'false'){
                    //API brings back file contents
                    $zip->addFromString($filename, $translation->get('body'));
                }
            }
            $translation = $client->downloadDocument($document->document_id, null, null);

            $filename = $name_and_extension[0].  ' (Source).'.$name_and_extension[1];
            $zip->addFromString($filename, $translation->get('body'));
            sleep(10);
            $zip->close();

        return response()->download($file, $name_and_extension[0].'.zip')->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
}
```

I'm unfamiliar with PHP streams and I don't have a debugger set up so I keep thinking it has something to do with how I am handling the stream. Because the other condition (the else if) is coming back as content of the file (string) and the if statement, the data is coming back as a stream resource, which I am unfamiliar with.

Comment: PK in the beginning shows it’s a zip file. The code is written to create a zip file and put files in it. Should it not do that?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen so up top the $file is supposed to be a zip. Which that part seems to work in most cases. And the two files in the if/else if statements are the files that I’m putting into the zip, and the if is the one throwing me problems. So I guess something with the logic in the if statement is causing the initial zip file to be turned into this weird binary string.

Answer (score -1):

Stream::factory
is used in Guzzle 5, use json_encode for Guzzle 6.